# mapreduce way to calculate user similarity matrix

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cosine-similarity

I have a list of many users (over 10 million) each of which is represented by a userid followed by 10 floating-point numbers indicating their preference. I would like to efficiently calculate the user similarity matrix using cosine similarity based on mapreduce. However, since the values are floating-point numbers, it is hard to determine a key in the mapreduce framework. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest solution would be the **[Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org/)** library. There are a couple of map-reduce similarity matrix jobs in Mahout that might work for your use case.

The first is Mahout's `ItemSimilarityJob` that is part of its recommender system libraries. The specific info for that job can be found **[here](https://builds.apache.org//job/Mahout-Quality/javadoc/org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/hadoop/similarity/item/ItemSimilarityJob.html)**. You would simply need to provide the input data in the required format and choose your `VectorSimilarityMeasure` (which for your case would be SIMILARITY_COSINE) along with any additional optimizations. Since you are looking to calculate user-user similarity based on a preference vector of ten floating point value, what you could do is assign a simple 1-to-10 numeric hash for the indices of the vector and generate a simple .csv file of vectorIndex, userID, decimalValue as input for the Mahout item-similarity job (the userID being a numeric  Int or Long value). The resulting output should be a tab separated text file of userID,userID,similarity.

A second solution might be Mahout's `RowSimilarityJob` included in its math library. I've never used it myself, but some info can be found **[here](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/mahout/mahout-core/org/apache/mahout/math/hadoop/similarity/RowSimilarityJob.html)** and in this **[previous stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429571/mahout-rowsimilarity)**. Rather than a .csv as input, you would need to translate your input data as a `DistributedRowMatrix`, the userIDs being the rows of the matrix. The output, I believe, will also be a `DistributedRowMatrix` sequence file containing the user-user similarity data you are seeking.

I suppose which solution is better depends on what input/output format you prefer. All the best.